# Delete Tabs of wc-setting in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to remove the general tabs of wc- ​​settign .
I tried using functions.php but without success.
What is the correct code ? Any other way ?

Comment: removing the tab is not correct thing i would say, better you make it display:none incase you don't want or to be hidden.

Answer (score -1):

try following

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menu_pages', 999);
function remove_menu_pages() {
    $remove_submenu = remove_submenu_page('woocommerce', 'woocommerce_settings');
}
```